# web api not receiving date from angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in angularjs. I have one date in angularjs for example 13-10-2017. In c# i have below field

```
 public DateTime LicenseExpiryDate { get; set; }
```

When i send 13-10-2017 in ajax request,LicenseExpiryDate  accepts as 0001-01-01. May i know how to fix this? I can see my angular date is in dd-mm-yy format and c# date default format is yyyy-mm-dd. 
i tried to convert it to yyyy-mm-dd as below

```
 function formatDateDOsetyymmdd(date) {
                debugger;
                var d = new Date(date),
                    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
                    day = '' + d.getDate(),
                    year = d.getFullYear();

                if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
                if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

                return [year,month, day].join('-');
            }
```

and this returns NaN-NaN-NaN
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: works fine with the right input ... how are you calling it? (and which browser?)

Comment: Thank you. I am accessing as $scope.modelname.

Comment: yeah, that shows **exactly** how you are calling the javascript function in your question

Comment: So how should i access it?

Comment: you're debugging it, right? ... what is the value of `date` when you're debugging

Comment: 13-10-2017 i will get like this.

Comment: well `new Date('13-10-2017')` results in ??? what?

Comment: `function formatDateDOsetyymmdd(date) { date = date.split('-').map(Number);
                var d = new Date(date[2], date[1] - 1, date[0]), ....rest of your code`

Comment: IDExpiryDate:new date($scope.idexpiry), this ends in ReferenceError: date is not defined

Comment: I don't even know what that code is - did you mean `new Date` (note, D instead of d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a string in form `dd-mm-yyyy` on input, what you want to do is turn that string into three numbers, and use those in the `new Date` call

```js
function formatDateDOsetyymmdd(date) {
    date = date.split('-').map(Number);
    var d = new Date(date[2], date[1] - 1, date[0]),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();
    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
    return [year,month, day].join('-');
}
console.log(formatDateDOsetyymmdd('13-10-2017'));
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting date in server side but problem is i selected 13-10-2017 but when i convert using formatDateDOsetyymmdd it became 2016-10-01. something wrong in above function?

Comment: Of course it did, I hardly ever post buggy answers :p (ok, I do it more often than I care to admit)

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment.js , if you can't do this in JavaScript means you can use it.

```
https://momentjs.com/
```